# Vue.js v-for increment some variable in looped component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to display a list of items on an event's agenda.

The event has a `start_date` end each item on the agenda has a `duration` in minutes, for example:

```
event:{
  start_date: '2017-03-01 14:00:00',
  agendas:[
      {id:1,duration:10},
      {id:2,duration:15},
      {id:3,duration:25},
      {id:4,duration:10}
  ]
}
```

Now, in my `event` component, I load `agendas` with a `v-for`:

```
<agenda v-for="(agenda,index) in event.agendas" 
        :key="agenda.id"
        :index="index" 
        :agenda="agenda">
```

In `agenda` component, I want to increment the time at which each item starts:

```
<div class="agenda">
  //adding minutes to start_date with momentJs library
  {{ moment(event.start_date).add(agenda.duration,'m') }} //this should increment, not add to the fixed event start date
</div>
```

Currently it only adds to the fixed event `start_date`... I would like to show the times `14:00` for event `1`, `14:10` for event `2`, `14:25` for event `3` and `14:50` for event `4`.

How can I increment the value in a `v-for` directive in Vue.js 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you already got an answer that works for you but I'll post this here in case anyone is looking for an alternate solution. The accepted answer might be good for an initial render of the agendas but will start to break if the agendas array is mutated or anything causes the list to re-render because the start time calculation is based on a stored value that gets incremented every iteration.

The code below adds a computed property (based on `event.agendas`) that returns a new array of of agenda objects, each with an added `start` property.

```
Vue.component('agenda', {
  template: '<div>Agenda {{ agenda.id }} — {{ agenda.duration }} min — {{ agenda.start }}</div>',
  props: {
    agenda: Object
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {...}, 
  computed: {
    agendas_with_start() {
      const result = [];

      let start = moment(this.event.start_date);
      for(let agenda of this.event.agendas) {
        result.push({
          id: agenda.id,
          duration: agenda.duration,
          start: start.format('HH:mm')
        });
        start = start.add(agenda.duration, 'm');
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
});
```

Then, in the template, the `agendas_with_start` computed property is used in the v-for:

```
<div id="root">
  <h3>Event Start: {{ event.start_date }}</h3>
  <agenda v-for="agenda in agendas_with_start" 
          :key="agenda.id"
          :agenda="agenda"></agenda>
</div>
```

Here's [a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peterburrell/pen/PpNLYb?editors=1010). The benefit of this approach is that if the underlying agendas array is mutated or re-ordered or the event start time changes or anything causes Vue to re-render the DOM, this computed property will be re-evaluated and the start times will be re-calculated correctly.

Comment: You are right. When mutating, the time continues to increment with the other answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Vue.js will actually let you bind prop values to methods on the parent's scope, so the easiest way will be to do something like this:

```
<agenda class="agenda" v-for="(agenda,index) in event.agendas"
    :key="agenda.id"
    :index="index"
    :agenda="agenda"
    :start-time="get_start_time(agenda.duration)">
</agenda>
```

And then the `get_start_time()` is a method within the parent's scope:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    time_of_day: '',
    event:{
      // ...
    },
  },

  methods: {
    get_start_time(duration) {
      if (this.next_event_start === '') {
        this.next_event_start = moment(this.event.start_date);
      } 
      this.event_start = this.next_event_start.format('h:mm a');
      this.next_event_start.add(duration, 'minutes');
      return this.event_start;
    },
  },
});
```

I've made a [quick CodePen](http://codepen.io/iamkether/pen/evZRvo?editors=1010) as a basic example to show it in action, but you'll need to update the actual code to compensate for multiple days.

Comment: Nice answer ... however, when I looked at the codepen it shows the agendas starting at 3:10 even though the event starts at 2. It seems like the get_start_time() method gets called more than once per agenda. Also, do you know if this will work if the agendas array is mutated? It seems like if you modify the agendas (add, remove, reverse), the start times will be re-calculated starting with the already incremented time_of_day value.

Comment: @Peter I think that might've resulted from re-applying the Moment library to itself on each iteration. I've fixed up the codepen to work properly now.

Comment: As for your question about the re-calculation, all you would need to do, based on the revisions I just did, would be simply to set `next_event_start` back to an empty string (`next_event_start = ''`) when you're modifying your agenda values. It should all re-calculate itself properly on the next `tick` of the Vue component update cycle.